# Emulator SD card comes up as "removed"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an AVD using the latest tools that came with Android Studio, which has quite a different AVD manager than what I used previously. I've tried creating AVDs with build 19 and 18 that are configured with SD cards of 100Mb or so, but my app (which required SD card storage) gets a return state of "removed" when it starts and can't proceed.

There is definitely an sdcard.img file of the expected size being created for the AVD, but it seems like it is not being mounted when the emulator runs. This never happened on AVDs that I created from Eclipse, although it's been months or more since I last created one at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your .android\avd\"avd_name".avd folder , and open `config.ini` ; Make sure you have ,

```
    hw.sdCard=yes
    sdcard.size=100M
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently I didn't use the right search terms since I just found this in another post.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio avd image had `hw.sdCard=yes` in my project. Had to edit `.android/avd/MyDevice/config.ini` to make things (camera app) work. Thanks!